# If I have only one PCIe EP and only one function, Do I need “interrupt-map” function in device tree (DTS)?

Tags: linux, interrupt-handling, device-tree, pci-e

I’m using legacy PCIe Interrupt mechanism(Virtual INTx), As per my PCIe controller user guide, In legacy Interrupt mechanism Assert or Deassert Virtual INTx messages will be received from the EP device and according to that PCIe Core it will generate or clear interrupt signal respectively.
If I have only one EP and only one function, Do I need “interrupt-map” function in device tree (DTS)? 
As per my understanding,

- PCIe EP will send Assert_INTA message
- PCIe RP decode this message and send Interrupt to Interrupt generating pin INTA_OUT
- In design INTA_OUT is directly connected to Interrupt  controller Input pin
- In Linux kernel this IRQ will invoke PCIe RP ISR and also Endpoint functions ISR
  Am I correct in my understanding ?

pci@0xfb000000 {

```
                    interrupts = <1 1>;  //PCIe RP INTA  IRQ1,  Only this info is enough ??
                    interrupt-parent = <&pic>;

                    /*Do we need follow info also ??? */
                    #interrupt-cells = <0x1>;
                    interrupt-map-mask = <0x0 0x0 0x0  0x7>;
                    interrupt-map = <  0x0 0x0 0x0  0x1  &pcie_intc 0x1
                                    0x0 0x0 0x0  0x2  &pcie_intc 0x2
                                    0x0 0x0 0x0  0x3  &pcie_intc 0x3
                                    0x0 0x0 0x0  0x4  &pcie_intc 0x4 >;
```

}